# Is there a way for SSRS to remember my parameters when switching between Design and Preview mode?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

When designing a report in SSRS, I put in my parameters and run the report.
If I see that there is a change in the Design that I need to make, I then have to flick back to the Design tab and make the change.

Once I go back to the Preview tab, I then have to again put in my parameters and wait for the report to run.

Is there a way to have SSRS remember the parameters that I had just entered and possibly keep the data in a cache so that when I flick back to the Preview tab, it just shows me the report rendered with my changes (but not new data etc)?

I'm pretty sure I can do this in Crystal Reports without having to re-enter parameters etc.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way for SSRS to remember the parameters when flicking between the design/preview tabs - however you could select default values for the parameters so that when you flick to the preview page, the values will automatically appear in the preview tab.

To do this, right click the parameter > Go to "Default Values" tab > Select "Specify Values" and add the default values you would like to use